# Resource Link Indetifier using PDO?

Tags: mysql

(new to PDO and limited experience with DB's in general) :)

I'm switching over to use PDO in a project..

and even though the data was getting dumped to the DB..there was a strange 'Warning'.. that displayed merging of table I was trying to use..(and another I wasnt)... SELECT()..etc even though I was trying to INSERT()..etc..

using the NON-PDO approach worked fine however (which seems a bit odd)..

example:

```
include("../_include/db_forms.php");       
mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tablename (timestamp, fullname, email, formcode, ipaddress, alldata) VALUES ('" .  date("YmdHis") . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) . "','" .     $formcode . "','" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($allData) . "')");
```

^ no warning/data dumps to DB just fine

after searching/asking around a bit...  it looked like another open database connection for the CMS (for other aspects of the page/header/footer include files..etc) is being used for the other queries, (or vice versa).. and this is causing the warning/problem.

I was told adding a resource link identifier would solve this...

now I understand what it is.., and why it is used (multiple DB's.. this is a reference to what one should be used/opened..etc.)

However.. I'm not exactly sure HOW to implement one.. especially using PDO approach.

here is my PDO approach/code:

```
require_once("../_include/db_pdo_fulllog.php"); //just a .php file with DEFINE()'s for DB connection details
// new DB routine PDO approach //
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tablename (timestamp, fullname, email, formcode, ipaddress, alldata) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DBSERVER . ";dbname=" . DBNAME, DBLOGIN, DBPASSWORD);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);   
    //$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO fulllog(timestamp, fullname, email, formcode, ipaddress, alldata) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    //timestamp
    $ts = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $ts);                                           
    //name
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $_POST['name']);
    //email
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $_POST['email']);
    //formcode
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $formcode);
    //ip address
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    //all data
    $allData = $_POST['session_title'] .' '. $_POST['session_type'] .' '. $_POST['description'] .' '. $_POST['goals'] .' ' . $_POST['faculty'] .' '. $_POST['chapter'];
    $stmt->bindParam(6, $allData);              

    //execute built statement
    $stmt->execute();
}                           
    catch(PDOException $e) {    
        echo $e->getMessage(); 
        die;
}
```

How can I add a resource link identifier to this...to stop the warning/error of having the multiple databases in use?

Thanks.

edit:

(since its been requested)

the error/warning message:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /usr/www/users/xxxxorg/xxxx.org/admincms/_includes/class.now_cms.php on line 126
>   Err (Table 'xxxx_forms.fulllogContent' doesn't exist) in query: SELECT n.NodeName, n.ContentId, n.ParentId, n.NodeOrder, n.ParentNode, n.ContentTitle, n.ContentType, n.Status, n.ShowOnNav, n.ShowNav, n.ShowOnSitemap, n.ForceSSL, n.TargetWindow, n.ResourceUrl, n.ShortTitle, n.Keywords, n.Description, n.CCount, n.COrderField, n.COrder, COALESCE(t.TemplateBody, dt.TemplateBody) as Template, COALESCE(ct.TemplateBody, dt.TemplateBody) as ChildTemplate, n.UserGroups, n.Comments, n.Sticky, IF(md.MetaId IS NULL, 0, 1) as HasMetaData FROM fulllogContent n LEFT JOIN fulllogTemplate t ON n.Template=t.TemplateId LEFT JOIN fulllogTemplate ct ON n.ChildTemplate=ct.TemplateId LEFT JOIN fulllogTemplate dt ON dt.TemplateId=dt.TemplateId AND dt.Status=2 LEFT JOIN fulllogSection s ON n.SectionId=s.SectionId LEFT JOIN fulllogMetaDefine md ON s.SectionId=md.SectionId WHERE n.Status=1 AND n.PubDate <= NOW() AND (n.ExpDate >= NOW() OR n.ExpDate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00') ORDER BY CONCAT(IF(n.ParentId=0, '', '/'), n.ParentNode), n.NodeOrder

Again..  my table is -not- 'xxxx_forms.fulllogContent'  but in fact: 'xxxx_forms.fulllog'

and most of the other stuff doesnt even apply to my table/DB either.. (nor am I doing a SELECT.. I'm doing an INSERT)..

SO it (somehow) still has the CMS database open/in use.. and is getting merged/mixed up with the one I want.

To re-iterate.. the data IS being dumped to the DB... but the page doesnt refresh/resolve and shows this warning/error..

Comment: Please, **read the error message**.

Comment: You down vote?  but dont supply an answer of any kind? or direction?

I have read the error.. and make no sense to me:  mysql_fetch_row()

I'm not even trying to do that.. or do a SELECT statement..etc

Nor does it have anything to do with: class.now_cms.php

As that just shows up whenever any syntax error happens..etc.

If I use the old way..mysql_query() there is no warning/error of this kind anywhere..  so it -is- related to this PDO chunk of code/approach.

Comment: this: Table 'xxxx_forms.fulllogContent' doesn't exist

Is false..well its correct in that, that table DOES NOT exists.. but I'm not even trying to use that table.. and as mentioned.. the data IS GETTING dumped/saved to the DB...

its getting something mixed/merged with the other table/connection that is also currently open..

Comment: It is not related to PDO. It's problem with whatever mysql_fetch_row() and xxxx_forms.fulllogContent table.

Comment: ok.. (youre not listenting)..  but if that the extent of the help.. then I guess I appreciate it anyways..  (funny how the other way of INSERTING() works just fine though??  no warning/error.  Also funny that using this PDO way/approach.. still DOES dump the correct database.. (but gives this odd error/warning anyways)..

*mysql_fetch_row()  not being used int he code anywhere by me (must be in some other aspect of the page/resources grabbing info from the CMS...


WHy does the other mysql_ approach work without a problem then?  using the same DB info/credentials?

Comment: it is **not** "this PDO way/approach" gives this odd error/warning anyways. But some other code. The sooner you realize it, the sooner you will solve the problem. PDO doesn't run any mysql_fetch_row() and PDO connection doesn't interfere with any mysql_connect()-opened connections. this is the only answer that can be given and you have got it long time ago already

Comment: Solution to fix seemed to be changing the define() constant names to be unique/different from the constant names the other connection was using.

Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

PDO object *IS* such a "link identifier" itself - so, you don't need anything else.

Therefore, your problem is not connected to PDO.

To get help on a particular error message you have to post this particular message whole and exact, instead of describing it in vague terms.

Comment: (not sure why its an answer either?)

Anyways.. the first post was updated with the warning/error message..

This is most definitely a mix-up of the two databases...  not sure how to fix it though it.. if you say link identifier is -not- the problem/cause/solution

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to fix this seemed to be changing the define() constant names to be unique/different from the constant names the other connection was using. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: if both connections are using the same credentials, then there is no point in using different constants

Comment: it was same credentials.. different table.. and for whatever reason, NOT changing it gives me the error/warning you saw above.

Thanks.